# Drawing electrical circuit and quantum circuit in same tikpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, quantikz

I want to include an [electrical circuit symbol](https://tikz.dev/library-circuits) (capacitor) and [`quantikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz) meter in the same `tikzpicture` environment, but this doesn't draw the `quantikz` symbol. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]

\draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (2,0);
\node at (1,-1) {capacitor};

\draw (0,-4) to |[meter]| (2,-4);
\node at (1,-5) {meter};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add node with the style `meter` defined by `quantikz`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,dsfont}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {circuits.ee.IEC} 
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]

        \draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (2,0);
        \node at (1,1) {capacitor};
        
        \node[meter, label=below:meter] (M) at (1,-2) {};   
        \draw  (M) edge  (0,-2) (2,-2) edge (M); 

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```